# how do I loop a php variable within a javascript script

Tags: php, javascript, loops, spry

I created a form with a text field that has Spry Validation (ie javascript).  The user can select the number of rows in the form from 1 to 10.  I need the code below to also expand but I'm not familiar enough with javascript to make it work.

$divkey is the variable that controls how many rows are in the form.

Original

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
var sprytooltip1 = new Spry.Widget.Tooltip("sprytooltip1", "#sprytrigger1");
</script>
```

so I need the line 'var sprytextfield1...' to repeat based on $divkey with the next line being 'var sprytextfield2...' and so on.  Can someone please rewrite this so it will work?

Trying to use php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php   for ($i = 0; $i < $divkey; $i++) { $num=$i+1; ?>  
var sprytextfield<?php echo $num;?> = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield<?php echo $num;?>", "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
<?php }?>
var sprytooltip1 = new Spry.Widget.Tooltip("sprytooltip1", "#sprytrigger1");
</script>
```

Trying to use javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numwrestler = <?php echo $wrestlerkey; ?>;
var sprytextfield = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numwrestler; i++) {
    var num = i+1;  
var sprytextfield[num] = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield"+num, "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
}
var sprytooltip1 = new Spry.Widget.Tooltip("sprytooltip1", "#sprytrigger1");
</script>
```

Comment: In either attempt, what was the JavaScript which was emitted to the browser?

Comment: It looks to me like the only error in your _JavaScript_ is the `var` in line beginning `var sprytextfield[num] = ...`, though you probably want to use index `i`, not `num` and it would be best practice to `var num;` outside of the loop and just set `num` inside (if you feel this variable necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use a Javascript array for this type of task.
Your code is mostly correct, but the `var` in your for loop is incorrect, and the creation of the `num` variable instead of just using `i` is redundant.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield = new Array();
var numwrestler = <?php echo $wrestlerkey; ?>;
for(var i = 0; i < numwrestler; i++){
    sprytextfield[i] = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield"+(i+1), "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
}

var sprytooltip1 = new Spry.Widget.Tooltip("sprytooltip1", "#sprytrigger1");
</script>
```

Be sure that your PHP variable(s) are defined in the file before you include them in your script.

Comment: This still gives `sprytextfield` form `[undefined, Object, Object, ..]`

Comment: very weird, anytime I make 'sprytextfield1 =' an array (ie sprytextfield[i] or sprytextfield[divnum] the javascript validation doesn't work.  however this DOES work:

Comment: var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield"+divnum, "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
-------  This is in the loop this way and the first sprytextfield1 doesn't mess it up...  is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you never define the variable `divkey`, by deafault the value will be 0.
Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php  $divkey = 10; for ($i = 0; $i < $divkey; $i++) { $num=$i+1; ?>  
var sprytextfield<?php echo $num;?> = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield<?php echo $num;?>", "none", {validateOn:["change"], maxChars:20});
<?php }?>
var sprytooltip1 = new Spry.Widget.Tooltip("sprytooltip1", "#sprytrigger1");
</script>
```

Please, note that the variable that you are using as index `$num` in every iteration of the loop will be increasing 2, because of the `i++` and the `$num=$i+1`

Comment: nope. `$num` is not increasing twice. It's getting `$i+1` and `$i` is increasing once every iteration. So if `$i=1` then `$num=2`, if `$i=2`, `$num=3` etc :)

Comment: That's true, my fault. Sorry :\

Comment: $ divkey is defined further up the page. This not the complete page.